# Serving pre-flight request using ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, preflight

I created a simple route in express using the code below.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get('/route1', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ data: "Route 1" });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

When I run `curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/route1`, I am getting `{"data":"Route 1"}` as response.

However, I tried running `curl -X OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/route1` to simulate a CORS pre-flight request. I received `GET,HEAD` as the response.

I was not able to find any documentation supporting this behaviour. Why did the above route respond to `OPTIONS` request?

(NOTE: I haven't used any other packages like `CORS`)

**EDIT**

Based on Quentin's answer, I tried issuing another `OPTIONS` request with relevant headers and with display headers flag in curl.

```sh
curl -i -X OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/route1 \
    -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
    -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-requested-with'
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Allow: GET,HEAD
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 8
ETag: W/"8-ZRAf8oNBS3Bjb/SU2GYZCmbtmXg"
Date: Wed, 03 Jul 2019 11:14:07 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

GET,HEAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPTIONS is a [standard HTTP method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7) with standard behaviour that has [built-in support in Express](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090ca91f6a387e66370d57ead94d886275e1/lib/router/route.js#L72).

The CORS spec layers additional semantics over the top of a regular OPTIONS request.

`curl -X OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/route1` makes an OPTIONS request, but it isn't simulating a prefight request (as it is missing a bunch of request headers that are required by the CORS specification). The response you get to that request doesn't include any CORS response headers either.

---

Re edit:

> I tried issuing another OPTIONS request with relevant headers

You missed out the `Origin` header, but as you can see, since you didn't set up CORS support in the Express app, the response still doesn't include any CORS response headers.